# How do I set up a publicly accessible API call for with an API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway Call with an associated Lambda call.

When I click on this link (it's used to confirm an email address) this is what I get:

```
https://<api-gateway-code>.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default/retrieveEmailConfStringAPI&p1=value1&p2=value2
```

Results:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Complete Headers:

```
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
content-length: 42
content-type: application/json
date: Mon, 06 Jan 2020 06:35:32 GMT
x-amz-apigw-id: <amazon-api-gateway-id>
x-amzn-errortype: MissingAuthenticationTokenException
x-amzn-requestid: <amazon-request-id>

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Host: <api-gateway-id>.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
TE: Trailers
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0
```

However, when I change this up a little to the following web address:

```
https://<api-gateway-id>.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default&p1=value1&p2=value2
```

This is the result:

```
{"message":"Forbidden"}
```

These are the raw headers results:

```
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
content-length: 23
content-type: application/json
date: Mon, 06 Jan 2020 06:45:13 GMT
x-amz-apigw-id: <amazon-api-gateway-id>
x-amzn-errortype: ForbiddenException
x-amzn-requestid: <amazon-request-id>

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Host: <api-gateway-id>.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0
```

This is the set up using the API Gateway in terms of a JSON object.

```
MacBook-Pro-2:lambdaZipFilesDev chauncey$ aws2 apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id <rest api id> --region us-east-2
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "<resource id>",
            "parentId": "<parent id>",
            "pathPart": "retrieveEmailConfStringAPI",
            "path": "/retrieveEmailConfStringAPI",
            "resourceMethods": {
                "ANY": {},
                "GET": {},
                "OPTIONS": {}
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "<parent resource>",
            "path": "/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the second command I ran in order to build this public API call:

```
MacBook-Pro-2:lambdaZipFilesDev chauncey$ aws2 apigateway update-method --rest-api-id <rest api id> --resource-id <resource id> --http-method GET --patch-operation op="replace",path="/apiKeyRequired",value="false"
{
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "authorizationType": "NONE",
    "apiKeyRequired": false,
    "requestParameters": {
        "method.request.querystring.p1": false,
        "method.request.querystring.p2": false
    },
    "methodResponses": {
        "200": {
            "statusCode": "200",
            "responseParameters": {
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": false
            },
            "responseModels": {
                "application/json": "Empty"
            }
        }
    },
    "methodIntegration": {
        "type": "AWS_PROXY",
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-2:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:<internal id code>:function:retrieveEmailConfStringAPI/invocations",
        "passthroughBehavior": "WHEN_NO_MATCH",
        "contentHandling": "CONVERT_TO_TEXT",
        "timeoutInMillis": 29000,
        "cacheNamespace": "<resource id>",
        "cacheKeyParameters": [],
        "integrationResponses": {
            "200": {
                "statusCode": "200",
                "responseParameters": {
                    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
                },
                "responseTemplates": {
                    "application/json": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I ran this command in order to create a public API call:

```
MacBook-Pro-2:lambdaZipFilesDev chauncey$ aws2 apigateway update-method --rest-api-id <rest-api-id> --resource-id <resource-id> --http-method GET --patch-operation op="replace",path="/authorizationType",value="NONE"
{
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "authorizationType": "NONE",
    "apiKeyRequired": false,
    "requestParameters": {
        "method.request.querystring.p1": false,
        "method.request.querystring.p2": false
    },
    "methodResponses": {
        "200": {
            "statusCode": "200",
            "responseParameters": {
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": false
            },
            "responseModels": {
                "application/json": "Empty"
            }
        }
    },
    "methodIntegration": {
        "type": "AWS_PROXY",
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-2:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:<aws-internal-id>:function:retrieveEmailConfStringAPI/invocations",
        "passthroughBehavior": "WHEN_NO_MATCH",
        "contentHandling": "CONVERT_TO_TEXT",
        "timeoutInMillis": 29000,
        "cacheNamespace": "<resource-id>",
        "cacheKeyParameters": [],
        "integrationResponses": {
            "200": {
                "statusCode": "200",
                "responseParameters": {
                    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
                },
                "responseTemplates": {
                    "application/json": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I just need to click the link and then for that to trigger my api link to my lambda function and for it to ahve some action on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is really simple and stupid.

```
https://<api-gateway-code>.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default/retrieveEmailConfStringAPI?p1=value1&p2=value2
```

The change is the `?` as opposed to the `&` in the parameter string.